# may i get index of elder loop in html?

Tags: html, loops, flask, indexing

I have 2 loops creating table:

```html
{% for row in row_data %} #first loop
    {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %} #second loop
      {{row_}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And i need to get first loops index. {{loop.index}} obviously returns second loops index.

Appreciate any help!

**UPD:**

That works for me:

```html
{% set firstIndex = loop.index %}
```

Comment: thats a loop inside HTML, so i think its HTML, but i might be wrong

Comment: HTML has no looping capability. It's only a markup language. Are you using Django?

Comment: Sorry for long answer. I am using flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the first loop index as a variable:

```
{% for row in row_data %} #first loop
    {% set firstIndex = loop.index %}

    {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %} #second loop
      {{row_}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```